# has_one relation in form in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have two models/tabels: room and room_location, that have a one on one relation:

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :room_location
end

class RoomLocation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :room
end
```

And this is what i want to do in my form in rooms.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Room do
  menu parent: 'Rooms'

  permit_params :name, :description, room_location_attributes: [:address, :city]

  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Roomsdata' do
      f.input :name, as: :string
      f.input :description
      f.has_one :room_location do |t|
        t.inputs do
          t.address
          t.city
        end
      end
     f.actions
    end
  end

end
```

The has_one doesnt work and if i do has_many, it says relation "room_locations" does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You should write in the params room_location_id instead of attributes

```
ActiveAdmin.register Room do
  menu parent: 'Rooms'

  permit_params :name, :description, room_location_id


  form do |f|

    address_id  = ''
    cs          = params[:id].present? ? Case.find(params[:id]) : nil

    unless cs.nil?
      address_id = cs.address.id unless cs.address.nil?
    end

   f.inputs 'Roomsdata' do
f.input :name, as: :string
      f.input :description
   
      f.input :room_location_id , :as => :select, :collection => room_location.order(address: :desc).to_a.uniq(&:address).collect {|room_location| [room_location.address, room_location.id] }, selected: room_location_id
f.input :room_location_id , :as => :select, :collection => room_location.order(city: :desc).to_a.uniq(&:city).collect {|room_location| [room_location.address, room_location.id] }, selected: room_location_id



     f.actions
    end
  end

end
```